# cannot resolve method newinstance()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-camera2

I am trying to understand how to use Api.camera2
and I am following google sample from this link 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

when I open the project it works but when I try it to rebuild the app to see  the effect of each part of the code I got the following error
cannotresolve method newinstance()
 it is the main java class

```js
package com.example.jimy.camera_app_learn;




import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container,  Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

}
```

i tried exporting project setting from the original project but it did not work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "i tried exporting project setting" but did you implement the `newInstance()` method or did you delete it from the original file?

Comment: i opened a new project and copied  the  code to the new project (also copied the all Xml files from the res folder) 
"i tried exporting project setting"  from the file tab i choose export settings in the original project and imported to the new project.
i think  i implemented in the fragment java file  AS fellow
" public class Camera2BasicFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback"

Comment: Sure, but "cannot resolve method" is a very clear error message if you did not implement the `newInstance()` method

Comment: thank you I appreciate your help 
 I was able to fix as you said by implementing a method
" public static Camera2BasicFragment newInstance() {
        
    }:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy the code from the Github repo you linked to?

[This line](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L412) has the `newInstance()` method, yet your error clearly says it cannot be found, so you should either implement it or just completely copy the code from that repository.

Answer (score 1):

Create this method in your target fragment:

```
public static CartFragment newInstance() {
    return new CartFragment();
}
```